# Error in .subset2(x, j) : subscript out of bounds in R

Tags: r, data.table

here is my code

```
    colClasses <- c("integer", rep("factor", 2140))

    > train_categorical <- fread(file.path(data_dir, "train_categorical.csv"), 
data.table=FALSE, na.strings="", showProgress=TRUE , colClasses=colClasses,drop="Id")

Read 1183747 rows and 2140 (of 2141) columns from 2.494 GB file in 00:07:35
    Error in .subset2(x, j) : subscript out of bounds
```

i think it is about colClasses but i'm kinda new to R, couldn't manage to get it work.

what should i do? please help, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use stringsAsFactors=TRUE instead of colClasses. This would then be `fread(file.path(data_dir, "train_categorical.csv"), 
data.table=FALSE, na.strings="", showProgress=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, drop="Id")`.

Comment: did you also try with `colClasses <- rep("factor", 2140)`? because the `colClasses`-vector has a longer length than the number of columns that is being read (because you drop one column)

Comment: also related to this issue I guess: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1426

Answer (score 1):

turns out with the recent data.table update we cannot use colClass and dropId simultaneously.

```
test_categorical <- fread(file.path(data_dir, "test_categorical.csv"), data.table=FALSE,
                            na.strings="", showProgress=TRUE,colClasses=colClasses)

test_categorical$Id <- NULL
```

that worked for me.